# Display UIPicker selection on a label in other View Controller

Tags: ios, ipad, delegates, uilabel, uipickerview

Working on an App for Ipad which has one main view controller and 3 popover views, each popover view has a UIPicker, I want to display in 3 different labels located in the main view controller the UIPickers selection, each label is asociated to its own UIPicker.
I had been trying with delegate  objects to pass the data from the pickers to the labels but something is wrong.
Any clue PLEASE!
Thanks.

Comment: "something is wrong"...

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use tags.

```
typedef enum { 
  FirstPicker = 1,
  SecondPicker,
  ThirdPicker 
} PickerTags;
```

When you create the picker, indicate which one it is by setting the tag either in storyboard or like this

```
picker.tag = FirstPicker;
```

In your picker callbacks it is now easy to identify the picker:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView 
      didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row 
       inComponent:(NSInteger)component {

   if (picker.tag == FirstPicker) { /* handle first picker */ }
   // etc.
}
```